# what causes WCF service functions not showing up at WCF Test Client?

Tags: c#, wcf, svc, wcftestclient

I took over a GET service code that ends with .svc from an already-left colleague. I loaded the webservice at WCF Test client, after the progression bar filled, there is no function or projects names showing up under my service projects.... What can cause that?

To further diagnose, I set up a test .svc Get service project myself, and it shows up in the my service projects. How strange....

I am using Visual Studio c# WCF service.

Comment: could you share the contract and service declaration?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a REST service, which won't show up in WCF Test Client.

Comment: How would I identify if the code is REST service or not?